# How to find if python object is a function or class method?

Tags: python

Let's take this example:

```
class Foo:
   def func(self):
        pass

def func():
   pass

f1 = Foo.func
f2 = func
```

I'm inspecting code and want to find out from `dir` or `inspect` if `f1` is a class method and `f2` is a function that is not part of any class ?

Comment: To what end - why does that matter?

Comment: Did you try looking over the names defined in `inspect` (via `dir`) to see if anything seems relevant? Maybe things that have `function`  or `method` in their names? Did you try using `help` on those things?

Comment: Does `func.__qualname__` work?

Comment: Following up on @NChauhan's suggestion, [PEP 3155 -- Qualified name for classes and functions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3155/) discusses the issue.

Comment: @NChauhan I believe this depends on not adding any methods after the class definition, e.g. `Foo.fn2 = lambda self: self`. `Foo.fn2.__qualname__ == <lambda>`

Answer (score 2):

Built-in inspect module has ismember and isfunction methods, https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html

However, unless you're doing something rather esoteric, it should not matter for user code.

EDIT: And if you *are* doing something esoteric, note that in the original question you asked about the attribute *on a class* `Foo`, not on an instance of `Foo`. And that makes a difference:

```
In [1]: def f(): return None

In [2]: class F:
   ...:     def f(self):
   ...:         return None
   ...: 

In [3]: import inspect

In [4]: [inspect.isfunction(_) for _ in [f, F.f, F().f]]
Out[4]: [True, True, False]

In [5]: [inspect.ismethod(_) for _ in [f, F.f, F().f]]
Out[5]: [False, False, True]
```

Comment: `ismethod` returns True for instance methods (`Foo().func`) but not for the functions defined at class level that beome instance methods when called (`Foo.func`). Its not going to work in this case. Since `type(Foo().func`) is `<class 'method'>`, and `type(Foo.func)` is `<class 'function'>`, there isn't a need to use `inpsect` to tell them apart.

Answer (score 0):

at this moment the only thing I found is `obj.__qualname__`  - if it contains a dot - this means it's a method of the class

but I'm not 100% sure this is perfect solution

Comment: Just checking for a dot gives false positives for nested functions, which have `__qualname__`s that look like [`f.<locals>.g`](https://ideone.com/ZhFkUu).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica can you give example when this can happen ?

Comment: I linked an example in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Just print the function names :

```
print('f1 =',f1)
print('f2 =',f2)
```

The output is :

```
f1 = <function Foo.func at 0x7f56105f3620>
f2 = <function func at 0x7f5611ce7e18>
```

This gives the full function names, including the parent class name if it is a class method as `Foo.func`

Comment: what you refer  seem a __repr__ which looks like it takes this from __qualname__

Comment: I am sorry. I didn't think of the similarity